# UndeclaredThrowableException thrown by IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, proxy-classes

I am using the decorator pattern for a `List<WebElement>`.Part of this decoration entails using a proxy.

When I call `get(index)` with an index that is out of bounds, it throws an `IndexOutOfBounds` exception, which is then caught by the proxy, and wrapped with an `UndeclaredThrowableException`.

My understanding is that it should **only** do this if its a checked exception.  `IndexOutOfBounds` is an *unchecked* exception, so why is it getting wrapped?

It still gets wrapped even if I add `throws IndexOutOfBounds` to my `invoke` function.

Here's my code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public WebElementList findWebElementList(final By by){
    return new WebElementList(
            (List<WebElement>) Proxy.newProxyInstance(this.getClass().getClassLoader(),
                    new Class<?>[] { List.class }, new InvocationHandler() {
        // Lazy initialized instance of WebElement
        private List<WebElement> webElements;

        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)
                throws Throwable {
            if (webElements == null) {
                webElements = findElements(by);
            }
            return method.invoke(webElements, args);
        }
    }), driver);
}
```

Here's part of my stacktrace:

```
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.get(Unknown Source)
at org.lds.ldsp.enhancements.WebElementList.get(WebElementList.java:29)
...
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
... 41 more
```

Comment: Silly question, perhaps: is there an intermediate exception which goes between the UndeclaredThrowableException and the IndexOutOfBoundsException and which is checked?  Perhaps some code has caught the IndexOutOfBoundsException, wrapped it in a checked exception and thrown that?  Does the missing part of your stacktrace contain any other exceptions?

Comment: @yashaka its been so long, I can't remember.  Sorry.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Vic Jang is right. You need to wrap the invocation in try-catch and rethrow the inner exception.

```
try {
  return method.invoke(webElements, args);
} catch (InvocationTargetException ite) {
  throw ite.getCause();
}
```

The reason is that "Method.invoke" wraps in InvocationTargetException those exceptions which are thrown in the method's code.

**java.lang.reflect.Method:**

> Throws:
>   ...
>   InvocationTargetException - if the underlying method
>   throws an exception.

**java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException:**

> InvocationTargetException is a checked exception that wraps an
>   exception thrown by an invoked method or constructor.

The proxy object's class doesn't have InvocationTargetException declared among its "throws". That leads to UndeclaredThrowableException.

Comment: While I don't have access to the code anymore, I'd guess that this is correct, so I'm going to accept it.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough reputation to comment.
Your problem seems very similar to [this one](http://amitstechblog.wordpress.com/2011/07/24/java-proxies-and-undeclaredthrowableexception/)

You can look at the solution there and see if that works.

In short, you need to wrap your `method.invoke` into `try{}`, `catch` the exception, and `throw` it again.

Comment: I don't understand how this would work. If I throw the same exception, it will still have the same stack trace (and look exactly the same).  However, if I throw a different exception (that isn't checked), it'll still have the wrong stack trace.  (I did read the article, but it didn't make sense why try/throw would make a difference)